# how we can generate the single sign on and reply url for new application in azure active directory

Tags: active-directory, azure, single-sign-on, saml

I am going to register a new  application in the Azure active directory for SAML login.
How can I generate my reply URL and single sign on url and entity ID ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find these details on the single sign in page of the app, under the "Enterprise Applications" section